Get contents of HTML style tag in ASP.NET using C#
I'm using an HTML to PDF library to create PDF documents from some of the HTML on an ASP.NET page. The HTML markup refers to CSS classes that are defined at the top of the page rather than inline, so the resulting PDF has all of the styling removed.
I need a way to pull the styles from the <head> section so that I can export those to the PDF document as well.

@K-J This isn't an existing application.  I'm using C# code and a PDF conversion library to translate part of an HTML page to a PDF, so I need to be the one to include the 
After looking at a few other ways, the solution ended up fairly straight forward.  First, I just added a runat="server" and ID to my style tag in the .aspx page:
<style runat="server" id="styAnswerTable" type="text/css">
    .answerTable thead {
        font-weight: bold;
    }
</style>

Then in the C# code, I was able to extract the contents of the tag and add back the script tags like this:
    string styles = String.Format("<style type='text/css'>{0}</style>", styAnswerTable.InnerText);

